# Issue with recent version of tasks and numbering

Tags: tasks

I recently updated my Miktex and now the package tasks is not behaving how it used to. Using `\task[]` would provide a non labeled task that wouldn't increase the enumeration, but now it increases the enumeration, giving me a headache.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tasks}
    \settasks{
    %debug,
    style=enumerate,
    label-format=\bfseries,
    label-align=right,
    label-width=21pt,
    label-offset=6pt,
    item-indent=27pt,
    column-sep=0.5em,}

\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}(2)
\task[] Not numbered
\task[] Not numbered
\task This used to be numbered 1
\task[] Not numbered
\task This used to be numbered 2
\task[] Not numbered
\task This used to be numbered 3
\task[] Not numbered
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image: tasks]

How can I achieve the previous effect, without having to label every single item by myself.

Comment: Arguably a bug. If you don't mind please report this here: https://github.com/cgnieder/tasks/issues

Comment: Very well, will report

Comment: This has been fixed in the latest version, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bug which has been fixed in version 1.3a (2021/02/20).